# How to write a perl script that counts lines with a specific pattern and prints it?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to write a script where it only greps if the first field has the same pattern.  I want to grep lines that have the same number three times.  Please see below.  Thanks everyone!!!

```
1    Cat

1    Dog

1    Mouse

2    Cat

3    Cat

3    Dog

4    Cat 

4    Dog

4    Mouse
```

Output should look like this:

```
1   Cat

1   Dog

1   Mouse

4   Cat

4   Dog

4   Mouse
```

Comment: And what have you tried thus far?

Comment: What have you read so far, where have you looked for the answer, this should be found in the first or second result of a google search.

Comment: Is the input sorted?  That is, can we expect lines with the same prefix to always be adjacent?  Also, is three a representative number of what you need in real life (and not, say, millions of lines)?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to slurp in the whole file first

```
 #  (?m)^(\d+)(?!\d).*\s*(?:^\1(?!\d).*\s*){2}

 (?m)
 ^ 
 ( \d+ ) (?! \d )
 .* \s* 
 (?:
      ^ 
      \1 (?! \d )
      .* \s* 
 ){2}
```

Perl test case

```
$/ = undef;

$str = <DATA>;

while ( $str =~ /(?m)^(\d+)(?!\d).*\s*(?:^\1(?!\d).*\s*){2}/g)
{
    print "Matched:\n$&\n";
}    

__DATA__

1    Cat

1    Dog

1    Mouse

2    Cat

3    Cat

3    Dog

4    Cat 

4    Dog

4    Mouse
```

Output >>

```
Matched:
1    Cat

1    Dog

1    Mouse


Matched:
4    Cat

4    Dog

4    Mouse
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data are as described (i.e. lines with the same number are consecutives and each line is followed by two line feed), you can do that:

```
while ($data =~ /^(([0-9]++).*(?:\R\R\2 .*){2})/mg) {
    $_ .= $1 . "\n\n";
}

chomp;
print;
```

Comment: I had a problem with mine where a '1 \n' , then '11 \n', then '1 \n', etc.. matched (because of .*). Forced me to put in ugly lookahead.

Comment: @sln: good point, I will put a space and a possessive quantifier.

Comment: Yep, faster than the assert.